# How to start a video from a special time and link it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, tags

I want to tag my videos at special times and link them too.
for example my video is 5 minute, from start to minute 1 is about USA and from minute 1 to minute 2 is about Iran and so on.

*and I have other page and want to link to that time and start from that time.*

**I dont know how to do it, with javascript and jquery or html or ...?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Your question need some edition, but maybe this is your Answer:

in HTML5 this is easy to do:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');
mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
mediaElement.played.end();      // Returns the number of seconds the browser has played
```

and you need a little skill of programming with java script to do it.

just add your time instate of 122:

```
   mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
```

and if you want to set your time as minute do this:

```
  var seekTime=(yourSpecialTimeinMinute)*60;
  mediaElement.currentTime = seekTime; // Seek to the minute that you want
```

a good documentation is here:[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Comment: Thank you very much, This is my answer @kermani